# Persistent error in caret: "wrong model type for regression"

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to do Leave One Out Cross Validation. I am following all the instructions, but don't really understand what I am doing, so I am getting an error. Maybe my dataset is too small, I can include it here:

```
 clay       oc   ph_h2o    avg_N2O sum_tmax
31.54643 2.654043 6.725000  5.8397204   1644.0
31.54643 2.654043 6.725000  8.9456498   1626.0
31.54643 2.654043 6.725000 36.6636187   1846.5
31.54643 2.654043 6.725000 27.9717408   1651.5
31.54643 2.654043 6.725000 13.7662532   1433.5
31.54643 2.654043 6.725000 28.4065759   1597.5
31.54643 2.654043 6.725000  9.7437375   1585.5
20.15455 1.371111 6.090909  2.8604854   1644.0
20.15455 1.371111 6.090909 11.4821949   1626.0
20.15455 1.371111 6.090909 20.1477475   1846.5
20.15455 1.371111 6.090909  3.9438700   1651.5
20.15455 1.371111 6.090909  4.8634605   1597.5
30.14316 3.224697 7.221811 10.2540652    802.5
30.14316 3.224697 7.221811 17.7039395    841.0
30.14316 3.224697 7.221811 19.3734159    983.5
30.14316 3.224697 7.221811 17.2422255    781.0
30.14316 3.224697 7.221811 17.9839534    412.5
18.06667 1.852857 5.911111  4.1653732   1012.5
18.06667 1.852857 5.911111  4.5732676   1201.0
18.06667 1.852857 5.911111  8.1417138   1003.5
 8.11250 0.886250 6.650000  0.4631667    818.0
 8.11250 0.886250 6.650000  2.1779861    397.5
 8.11250 0.886250 6.650000  1.6355573    641.5
 8.11250 0.886250 6.650000  2.8754931    259.5
22.47405 1.816556 5.684229  4.5025055   1324.0
22.47405 1.816556 5.684229  3.6881473   1634.5
22.47405 1.816556 5.684229  4.7470418   1370.0
22.47405 1.816556 5.684229  8.2378739   1559.5
```

The code I try on these is:

```
train_control<-trainControl(method="LOOCV")
control<-train(avg_N2O ~., data=slim, trControl=train_control, method="nb")
```

All classes should be numeric, and they are.

I've used linear regression to look at the relationship of these variables to avg_N2O, but it has been suggested that I use LOOCV. I would like to have a predictive model in the end and this is my training set.

Comment: instead of `method='nb'` do `method='lm'`

Comment: It worked! Now to figure out what the results mean.